# change url zend

Tags: zend-framework, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

`class ContactusController extends Zend_Controller_Action` it result `url/contactus`.I like to change `url/contact-us` . How can i add "-" in url. Please help me to find-out the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by adding a route with Zend_Router .

```
$router = $this->_front->getRouter();

$router->addRoute('contactus', 
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('contact-us',
        array(
            'controller' => 'contactus',
            'action'     => 'index',
            'category'   => null
        )
    );
);
```

Can read more about it from http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: way too much complex for such a simple task IMHO.

Comment: @regilero Router is the good way, I never say its easy to learn , but once you learn its the easiest way to change the url quickly than renaming the controller and making any changes in the _forward , _redirect methods if you have applied :) .

Comment: well, it depends in fact if you're in the beginning of development or working on an old codebase. Adding router 'exception' rules for all url that you need with a '-' is adding a lot of processing tasks on the dispatcher, that could in fact be managed by the default router rules. It's a workaround solution, it's not the classical way of having '-' in an url.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
class ContactusController extends Zend_Controller_Action
```

Use a camelCase name:

```
class ContactUsController extends Zend_Controller_Action
```

with a `U` and not `u`.

Same thing for yout filename, should be a `controller/ContactUsController.php`. Then the url is by convention `contact-us`, `contact-us/action`, etc.